# how can i calculate a proportion with SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sum, inner-join

i'm beginner in SQL and i'm trying to calculate a proportion but i don't understand why the code below doesn't work. Can someone help me please ? there is a way to sum(count()) ? thanks for your help.

```
select
  total_piece as Nb_piece, 
  count(id_vente) as Nb_appartement,
  count(id_vente)/sum(Nb_appartement) as "%"
from (
  select *
  from vente as V
  inner join bien as B on V.id_bien = B.id_bien
  where type_local = 'Appartement'
) as VB
group by Nb_piece
order by Nb_piece asc
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It's not fully clear to me what you want.

Comment: what is the expression `sum(Nb_appartment)` meant to do? most rdbm systems don't allow an alias to be defined (NB_appartement or NB_piece) and refrenced/use din the same subquery (you referred to them in sum() and group by, respectively). If the sum is the total no of appartments in the whole table you have to obtain that as a separate subquery or use a windowing function. Furthermore dividing a smaller integer (count(...) by a larger one yields zero in most systems; you need to type cast one or the other to a decimal/float type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  total_piece as Nb_piece, 
  count(id_vente) as Nb_appartement,
  count(id_vente)/sum(Nb_appartement) as "%"
from (
  select *
  from vente as V
  inner join bien as B on V.id_bien = B.id_bien
  where type_local = 'Appartement'
) as VB
group by total_piece
order by Nb_piece asc
```

### You can't use an alias to group in SQL, use the actual column name to group by